# How to make color bar above navigator in Highstock?

Tags: highcharts

I have chart showing time data. I have two points back in time which I need to "mark" in the chart.

I currently indicate these two by plotlines, but would like to show bar, with let's say green and blue bars showing the timespans (for example -13days from now with blue and -90days -> -13days with red).

I would use plotBands, but I can't specify their height and do not want to have them all over the chart.

Is there some way? I saw something about translating pixels and drawing rectangle, but wasn't able to make it work. Also - I zoom a lot in this chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Renderer and add custom shape. In other cases, please attach mockup of your goal.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer

Comment: I've managed to add the bars, with correct positioning (converted time data to pixels), but now I am solving another issue with it. I have the cart in jQuery vertically resizible div and if I resize, the chart changes it's height, but my bars stay at the same position. I am now trying to figure out, how to get rid of the bar and draw a new one.

Comment: Fixed. I remote the <rect> element with specific fill color attribute from DOM. $( "rect[fill='#85a5ff']" ).remove();